# Insert Session variable into PHP form processing script

Tags: php

I need to make sure users don't go to the download page unless they fill out the form on the register page. I need help inserting a session variable into the submission script, something like

```
$_POST['authenticated']  = 'yes';
```

Then on the download page require this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if($_SESSION['authenticated'] !== 'yes') {
   header("Location: http://domain.com/default.php");
 };
?>
```

I need to make them successfully fill out the form - then add it to the session - then once on the page - purge the session info but don't know how

I need a push in the right direction on how to require the form to be filled out in order to get to download page.

***EDIT***
on purchase-registration.php (form) I added this

```
$authReq=$_SESSION['authReq']=rand(1,65535);
```

and in the form(s) on that page I added this

```
<input type='hidden' name='authreq' value='<?PHP=$authReq?>'>
```

In the processor script (form submit) I added this:

```
"$authReq = $_POST["authReq"];"
```

and on the final page, the download-software.php which Im trying to restrict access to I added this

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if($_SESSION['authReq']==$_POST['authReq']) {
  header("Location: http://kinetick.com/V3/download-free.php");
  };
?>
```

no joy, is this incorrect?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually handle that is:

on the page that renders the form:

```
$authReq=$_SESSION['authReq']=rand(1,65535);
```

on the form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='authreq' value='<?PHP=$authReq?>'>
```

and on the submitted page

`if($_SESSION['authReq']==$_POST['authReq'])`....

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a random number for a session variable rather than just using the same session variable for every user, such as the question uses'authenticated'?

Comment: @FatherStorm, so on the register page, add the $authReq var, add a hidden input in the form and on the download page the if conditional? Want to make sure Im correct before mucking up my code. again.

Comment: the advantage of a random number is that it just adds a layer of security. It's NOT necessary as long as you remember to clear that session variable, but because of the way it works, it automatically clears out the check value and resets it to a new one. and YES, generate the $authReq at the time you render the reg form and check it on submit.

Comment: That's basically just CSRF protection (which is quite different from what the question is asking, if I read it correctly).  Besides, you probably want much higher entropy in the calculation, since it's susceptible to a [Birthday Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).  Seeing how 65k possibilities is 16 bit, you'd only need approximately 256 requests to have a 50% chance of guessing.  And only about 37 requests to have a 1% chance of guessing....  So you really should see to `getrandmax()` if you're using an int.  Or you should use `uniqid` which has much higher entropy...

Comment: @Father Storm - sorry, im not getting it. I added the "$authReq=$_SESSION['authReq']=rand(1,65535);" on the page that has the form (download-register.php) and the hidden input "<input type='hidden' name='authreq' value='<?PHP=$authReq?>'>" on both forms on that page. Then added "$authReq = $_POST["authReq"];" on my processor script, didn't work. I can hit download page directly

Comment: make sure it's if($_SESSION['authReq']==$_POST['authReq']){ } . If you don't use the double equal signs you are setting and NOT evaluating...

Comment: @FatherStorm, in this case would "!==" be appropriate, so if its not equal it bounces them to another page

Comment: CHECK http://craigslist.fatherstorm.com/stackoverflow.php for an example with code view link at bottom

Comment: @FatherStorm link is gone. Anyway, Im not rendering any forms, its a static form on a page, that submits via a PHP script. The script collects the info, injects it into a database and returns you to the end page. Will this work?